# PHP7 Поведение NULL

Tags: php7

Это только у меня? Или я что то не так делаю?

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr['key'] = NULL;

var_dump(isset($arr['key']));
//bool(false)

var_dump(is_null($arr['key']));
//bool(true)

var_dump(is_null($arr['any_key']));
//bool(true)
```

Как проверить существование ключа?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы прочитаете документацию, то увидите, что isset проверяет не только наличие переменной, но и ее соответствие null в том случае, если она существует - это та самая неинтуитивность PHP, про которую все говорят. В остальных случаях поведение PHP предписывает вернуть ему хотя бы что-нибудь по несуществующему ключу (возможно, выкидывая предупреждение), и это значение - null.

Для того, чтобы определить наличие ключа в массиве, вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Answer (score 1):

Что именно вас смущает в результатах выводов? Такие результаты вы получите [на всех версиях PHP](https://3v4l.org/g5d1V), начиная с 5.4. А существование ключа, кроме isset(),  можно проверить и с помощью функции [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php). Значение, если вы всё-таки это имели в виду - [empty()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php)

Comment: тем, что isset - это конструкция, а array_key_exists функция, isset отработает быстрее, если ключ будет найден и определен и не равен null он отработает true, а если ключа нет то false. И еще кстате тем, что если вдруг прилетит $key null и функция array_key_exists выдаст Notice о $key;  - $key ?? $key['name'] ?? null

Comment: @And, вы это всё к чему писали и как это связано с вопросом ТС?

Comment: к тому, что isset в помощь или замену ?? - к тому же тип null указывает, о не существовании.

Comment: @And, думаю, что на этом лучше остановиться, т.к. на дешифровку ваших высказываний может уйти много времени.

Answer (score 0):

`null` - это специальное значение, которое обозначает либо неинициализированную переменную, либо удаленную (`unset`), либо ту, которой явно присвоили `null`.

Проверяют существование ключа при помощи `isset()`

```
if(isset($arr['key'])) {
   ...
}
```

В PHP7 поведение, связанное с `null` не изменялось.

Comment: тогда почему здесь isset выдает false?

Comment: @OxelNet Потому что вы явно присвоили $arr['key'] значение null.